# spring-boot embedded tomcat doesnot start [2.2.6 vs 2.2.2]

Tags: spring-boot

1) Clone this repo https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot

2) Navigate to complete directory and run

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

You will be able to navigate to http://localhost:8080/ to see greetings from spring boot.
This is as expected.

3) Now, let's update spring-boot version from 2.2.2 to 2.2.6 in pom.xml.

```
<version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
```

Try `.\mvnw spring-boot:run` Tomcat does not come up anymore. The http endpoint doesnot work for the same reason. What am I missing in this version upgrade?

Comment: what do you see in server logs? Any error/messages?

Comment: My best guess is that a jar file got corrupted when you upgrade to 2.2.5. It is impossible to say without sharing the log.

Comment: Thanks Stephane for pointing that out. I found a related error in the logs so I cleared the local maven repo -- `invalid LOC header (bad signature)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stephane Nicoll pointed out, I saw the logs to find these errors.

[ERROR] error reading /Users/testUser/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

[ERROR] error reading /Users/testUser/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.13.2/assertj-core-3.13.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

[ERROR] error reading /Users/testUser/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.8/byte-buddy-1.10.8.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

I cleared the .m2/repository/ directory and the subsequent downloaded worked fine.

Thanks Stephane.